# Use of a CompletionBlock in different Classes

Tags: objective-c, block

I have Class A and Class B. I want each to use a completion block, so I create

```
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)()
```

in both .h files.

That gives me a redefinition error. How can I use that name in multiple files? I would rather not have to use

```
typedef void(^ACompletionBlock)();

typedef void(^BCompletionBlock)();
```

In their respective .h files. I have no experience with `typedef` usage.

Comment: put the `typdef` into a header file (e.g. `Constants.h`), and import it in `ClassA` and `ClassB`. you will be able to use the same type in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `CompletionBlock`s are (1) identical and (2) not tied to any specific set of types, consider placing this definition in a common header included from both `ClassA.h` and `ClassB.h` files:

CompletionAction.h

```
typedef void(^CompletionAction)();
```

ClassA.h

```
#include "CompletionAction.h"

@interface ClassA
-(void)runWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionAction)onDone;
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
#include "CompletionAction.h"

@interface ClassB
-(void)runSomethingElseWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionAction)onDone;
@end
```

Another option for simple blocks like that is to define their type "inline" as part of method declaration, thus avoiding a `typedef`, like this:

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA
-(void)runWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)())onDone;
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB
-(void)runSomethingElseWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)())onDone;
@end
```